# Getting unixtimestamp from Phalcon model

Tags: php, phalcon

How can you get unixtimestamp from Phalcon models. Currently I am getting the timestamps in string format like **2015-08-31 13:28:20**. Is there a way to use like UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myTime) in model getters?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for `strtotime` php function

```
echo strtotime("2015-08-31 13:28:20");
```

Will output `1441042100`

Comment: Well that's the way I am doing it currently, but handling timezones in PHP is just awful. The database may even have different timezone and then all the timestamps will be messed up. I think the safest way would be to get unixtimestamp directly from MySQL.

Comment: If you're storing dates as `datetime` type, the timezone shouldn't interfere.

Comment: It is not an answet for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that there is no out-of-box solution for you right now in Phalcon. One thing that crosses my mind is to use `skipAttributesOnCreate([]);` ([docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/models.html#skipping-columns)) on column that has its default set in SQL to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and than harvest it in getter method.